# Big Query Union Joins

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ambiguity

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error: Union results in ambiguous schema. [Bookings] is ambiguous and is aliasing multiple fields. Aliased fields: z.Bookings, Bookings
```

I have looked at the other threads here and made (what I thought) were the correct changes however no luck.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
  CASE WHEN depdate between DATE('1970-01-02') AND DATE('2013-10-31')  THEN 'OLD'
       WHEN depdate between DATE('2013-11-01') AND DATE('2014-04-30') THEN 'W13'
       WHEN depdate between DATE('2014-05-01') AND DATE('2014-10-31') THEN 'S14'
       WHEN depdate between DATE('2014-11-01') AND DATE('2015-04-30') THEN 'W14'
       WHEN depdate between DATE('2015-05-01') AND DATE('2015-10-31') THEN 'S15'
       WHEN depdate between DATE('2015-11-01') AND DATE('2016-04-30') THEN 'W15'
       WHEN depdate between DATE('2016-05-01') AND DATE('2016-10-31') THEN 'S16'
       WHEN depdate between DATE('2016-11-01') AND DATE('2017-04-31') THEN 'W16'
       WHEN depdate between DATE('2017-05-01') AND DATE('2017-10-31') THEN 'S17'
       WHEN depdate > DATE('2017-11-01') THEN 'OTHER'
       WHEN depdate = DATE('1970-01-01') THEN 'ALL' ELSE 'N/A' END as Season,
  c.GUID as MyCode,
  c.MasterCode as MasterCode,
  c.Name as PropertyName,
  c.Destination as Gateway,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a.Type = 'Quote' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Visits,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a.Type = 'Booking' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Bookings,"CHARTER"as Journey
FROM
[dataset.GUID_Master_Mapping]  c 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT 
   DATE(concat(left([date],4),'-',substring([date],5,2),'-',substring([date],7,2)))  as VisitDay,  
   UPPER(substring(hits.page.pagePath, instr(lower(hits.page.pagePath),'accomguid')+10,8)) as MyCode,
   CASE WHEN hits.page.pagePath like '%booking?%' THEN 'Booking' ELSE 'Quote' END as Type,      
        ifnull(DATE(concat(substring(hits.page.pagePath,
                instr(lower(hits.page.pagePath),'deptdate')+15, 4),'-',            
          substring(hits.page.pagePath, 
                instr(lower(hits.page.pagePath),'deptdate')+12, 2),'-',
                substring(hits.page.pagePath, 
                instr(lower(hits.page.pagePath),'deptdate')+9, 2))),DATE('1970-01-01')) as depdate, 
           concat(fullVisitorId, string(visitId)) as UniqueVisit  
      FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([data set], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),-14,'DAY'),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
    WHERE hits.type = 'PAGE'
      AND (hits.page.pagePath like 'web url/cust?%'   
        or hits.page.pagePath like 'web url/booking?%'
           )
       AND UPPER(substring(hits.page.pagePath, instr(lower(hits.page.pagePath),'accomguid')+10,1)) = 'H' 
       and trafficSource.medium <> 'newrelic'
    GROUP EACH BY 
        VisitDay, MyCode, depdate, Type, UniqueVisit) a
        ON c.GUID = a.MyCode
    WHERE c.Brand <> 'Z' 
    AND c.Season=CASE WHEN depdate between DATE('1970-01-02') AND DATE('2013-10-31')  THEN 'OLD'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2013-11-01') AND DATE('2014-04-30') THEN 'W13'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2014-05-01') AND DATE('2014-10-31') THEN 'S14'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2014-11-01') AND DATE('2015-04-30') THEN 'W14'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2015-05-01') AND DATE('2015-10-31') THEN 'S15'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2015-11-01') AND DATE('2016-04-30') THEN 'W15'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2016-05-01') AND DATE('2016-10-31') THEN 'S16'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2016-11-01') AND DATE('2017-04-31') THEN 'W16'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2017-05-01') AND DATE('2017-10-31') THEN 'S17'
               WHEN depdate > DATE('2017-11-01') THEN 'OTHER'
               WHEN depdate = DATE('1970-01-01') THEN 'ALL' ELSE 'N/A' END
    GROUP EACH BY Season, MyCode, Gateway, PropertyName,MasterCode),



    (SELECT Season,MyCode,MasterCode,PropertyName,d.Gateway as Gateway,Visits,Bookings,Journey
    FROM
    [data set.Resorts_Gateway_Mapping]d
    RIGHT JOIN EACH

    (SELECT 
          CASE WHEN depdate between DATE('1970-01-02') AND DATE('2013-10-31')  THEN 'OLD'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2013-11-01') AND DATE('2014-04-30') THEN 'W13'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2014-05-01') AND DATE('2014-10-31') THEN 'S14'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2014-11-01') AND DATE('2015-04-30') THEN 'W14'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2015-05-01') AND DATE('2015-10-31') THEN 'S15'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2015-11-01') AND DATE('2016-04-30') THEN 'W15'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2016-05-01') AND DATE('2016-10-31') THEN 'S16'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2016-11-01') AND DATE('2017-04-31') THEN 'W16'
               WHEN depdate between DATE('2017-05-01') AND DATE('2017-10-31') THEN 'S17'
               WHEN depdate > DATE('2017-11-01') THEN 'OTHER'
               WHEN depdate = DATE('1970-01-01') THEN 'ALL' ELSE 'N/A' END as Season,
          c.GUID as MyCode,
          c.MasterCode as MasterCode,
          c.Name as PropertyName,
          c.Destination as Gateway,
          SUM(CASE WHEN e.Type = 'Quote' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Visits,
          SUM(CASE WHEN e.Type = 'Booking' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Bookings, "LIPS"as Journey

      FROM
      [dataset.GUID_Master_Mapping]  c 
     RIGHT JOIN EACH  


     (SELECT 
           DATE(concat(left([date],4),'-',substring([date],5,2),'-',substring([date],7,2)))  as VisitDay,  
           UPPER(substring(hits.page.pagePath, instr(lower(hits.page.pagePath),'accomguid')+10,8)) as MyCode,
           CASE WHEN hits.page.pagePath like '%booking?%' THEN 'Booking' ELSE 'Quote' END as Type,      
                ifnull(DATE(concat(substring(hits.page.pagePath,
                        instr(lower(hits.page.pagePath),'deptdate')+15, 4),'-',            
                        substring(hits.page.pagePath, 
                        instr(lower(hits.page.pagePath),'deptdate')+12, 2),'-',
                        substring(hits.page.pagePath, 
                        instr(lower(hits.page.pagePath),'deptdate')+9, 2))),DATE('1970-01-01')) as depdate, 
           concat(fullVisitorId, string(visitId)) as UniqueVisit  
          FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([.ga_sessions_], DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),-14,'DAY'),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
          WHERE hits.type = 'PAGE'
           AND (hits.page.pagePath like 'web url/cust?%'   
            or hits.page.pagePath like 'web url/booking?%'
           )
          AND UPPER(substring(hits.page.pagePath, instr(lower(hits.page.pagePath),'accomguid')+10,1)) = 'H' 
           and trafficSource.medium <> 'newrelic'
          GROUP EACH BY 
          VisitDay, MyCode, depdate, Type, UniqueVisit) e  
    ON c.GUID = e.MyCode
    WHERE c.Brand = 'Z'
    GROUP EACH BY Season, MyCode, Gateway, PropertyName,MasterCode)z
    On z.Gateway=d.Resort)
```

I realize this is a lot to look at but any help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that this directly solves the original problem, but consider giving [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) a shot in the future. It has fewer surprising edge cases and handles unions as you with expect with, well, standard SQL :)

Answer (score 0):

Had to rename the z table with z. as "xyz"